# data is not displaying in jquery DataTable

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I am trying to fetch data from database and display in jquery DataTable but the data is not displaying in DataTable. Table is

```
ordered_books with attributes 'BookID', 'BilledNum','BilledDate', 'Qunatity', 'Price', 'Remarks'
```

view page code

```
<table id="showBooksIn" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>BOOK ID</th>
            <th>BILLED DATE</th>
            <th>BILLED NUMBER</th>
            <th>QUANTITY</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>REMARKS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#showBooksIn').DataTable({
            "processing":true,
            "serverside":true,
            "ajax":{{route('data')}}
            "columns":[
                {"data": "BookID"},
                {"data": "BilledNum"},
                {"data": "BilledDate"},
                {"data": "Qunatity"},
                {"data": "Price"},
                {"data": "Remarks"},
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

controller code

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('pages.booksin', $this->fetchData());
    }

function fetchData()
{
    $ordered_books = OrderedBook::select('BookID', 'BilledNum','BilledDate', 'Qunatity', 'Price', 'Remarks');
    return Datatables::of($ordered_books)->make(true); //return an instance of the class or interface you request
}
```

model code

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrderedBook extends Model
{
    //
}
```

route code

```
Route::resource('/order','OrderedBookController');
Route::get('/order/data','OrderedBookController@fetchData')->name('data');
```

I think the problem is with DataTable javascript code. But I am not sure. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

This line define,**"processing":true,"serverside":true,** are you using server side datatable.

Please follow bellow link to implement.

[Server side datatable using laravel](https://gist.github.com/itzikbenh/5e99c957101b2b2837092c778cbd3ac0)

Answer (score 1):

**Try after change**

```
"ajax":{{route('data')}} to ajax: '{!! URL("/data") !!}',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your AJAX route with quotes like this,

```
'{!! route("data") !!}'
```

Answer (score 0):

also `name` index need to on `columns` as like:

```
"columns":[
   {data: "BookID", name: "BookID"},
   {data: "BilledNum", name: "BilledNum"},
   {data: "BilledDate", name: "BilledDate"},
   {data: "Qunatity", name: "Qunatity"},
   {data: "Price", name: "Price"},
   {data: "Remarks", name: "Remarks"},
 ]
```

> removed double quotation from `data` instead of `"data"` to `data`.

So, if need to you can copy and paste above code.